# Using PHPExcel to convert more then 1 sheet from xls to csv

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am using the following code which converts the xls file to csv.
This works for the first sheet but i have several that need doing. These sheets will always be the same name.
Is there away to do all the sheets and not just do the first active one.

```
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("all-euro-data-2015-2016.xls");
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->setDelimiter(";");
$writer->setEnclosure("");
$writer->save("test123.csv");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you only write the active sheet. You have to iterate over the different sheets in the excel-file and write them to seperate csv files.

```
foreach ($excel->getWorksheetIterator() as $workSheetIndex => $worksheet) {
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($workSheetIndex);    
    $writer->setSheetIndex($index);
    $writer->save("test123_" . $worksheet->getTitle() . ".csv");    
}
```

Comment: `code` require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("all-euro-data-2015-2016.xls");
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
foreach ($excel->getWorksheetIterator() as $workSheetIndex => $worksheet) {
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($workSheetIndex);    
    $writer->setSheetIndex($index);
    $writer->save("test123_" . $worksheet->getTitle() . ".csv");    
}`code`

Comment: this is what i did but i just get the errors:


Notice: Undefined variable: index in /home/admin/JARRATTPERKINS.COM/xls2csv.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: in /home/admin/JARRATTPERKINS.COM/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php on line 581

Fatal error: Call to a member function getHighestDataColumn() on a non-object in /home/admin/JARRATTPERKINS.COM/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/CSV.php on line 128

what is index supposed to be?

Comment: Added the index as $index++

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake. $index should of course be $workSheetIndex

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PHPExcel, but the delimiter should be a comma not a semicolon for CSV files.